# How to handle multiple ajax requests

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

NOTE:

I gave up on trying to do the processing in one go, and just let it return after every x number of sends.

Two paths, 
/sms?action=send
/sms?action=status

Let's say that the send path starts sending 10,000 sms messages via REST api calls.

I make a call to that page via ajax.

Then every few seconds, I make a call to /sms?action=status to see how the progress is going, and to update a progress bar.

The status path returns false if no messages are being sent.

What ends up happening is that the ajax call to the SEND path gets the ajax success: function called almost instantly, even though I know the script is taking 1+ minute to complete execution.

My progress bar never gets shown because the status ajax call (which is in a set interval with a few second delay) never seems to actually get called until the send call completes.

I'm trying to put the relevant code in here, but it may not be as clear as it should be without all the context.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var smsInterval = 0;
var smsSending = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var charCount = 0;
  var smsText = "";
  var smsTotal = <?php echo $options["smsTotal"]; ?>;


  <?php if($options["sending"]): ?>
     smsStatus();
     smsSending = true;
     smsInterval = setInterval("smsStatus()", 5000);

  <?php endif; ?>
  $("span#smsadmin_charcount").html(charCount.toString());


  //send button
  $("div#smssend").click(function() {
     if(smsSending == true) {
        return false;
     }

     smsStatus();

     var dataString = $("#smsadmin_form").serialize();
     smsSending = true;
     $("div#smssend").html("Sending...");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/admin/sms",
        data : dataString,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(request, error) {
           $("div.notice.sms").html("ERROR "+error+ "REQUEST "+request);
        }
        });
  });
  });

  function smsStatus() {
  var dataString = "smsaction=status&ajax=true";

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $base_url; ?>/admin/sms",
        data : dataString,
        success: function(data) {
           //data being false here indicates the process finished
           if(data == false) {
              clearInterval(smsInterval);
              var basewidth = $("div.sms_progress_bg").width();
              $("div.sms_progress_bar").width(parseInt(basewidth));
              $("div.sms_progress_notice").html(parseInt(100) + "% Complete");
              smsSending = false;
              $("div#smssend").html("Send To <?php echo $options["smsTotal"]; ?> Recipients");
           } else {
              var pcomplete = parseFloat(data);

              $("div.sms_progress_bg").show();
              var basewidth = $("div.sms_progress_bg").width();
              $("div.sms_progress_bar").width(parseInt(basewidth * pcomplete));
              $("div.sms_progress_notice").html(parseInt(pcomplete * 100) + "% Complete");
           }
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
           $("div.notice.sms").html("ERROR "+error+ "REQUEST "+request);
        }
        });
```

}

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear, the specific details don't really matter, 2 ajax calls, one starts a process that takes a minute or two and sends a bunch of email or sms messages, and another ajax call that can get the number of messages that have been sent, or the percent or whatever. The status call won't seem to happen until the process call finishes. That's what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point, but inside the $("div#smssend").click you got this line:

```
smsStatus();
```

shouldn't it be:

```
smsInterval = setInterval("smsStatus()", 5000);
```

and INSIDE the success: function(data) for /admin/sms ?

Answer (score 0):

If the send part is sending out 10k messages, and the status returns true if currently sending a message, and false if in between sending, then you have a design issue.

For example, what is status supposed to be showing?

If status is to show how many of a certain block have been sent, then what you can do is to submit the message to be sent (or addresses), and get back some id for that block.

Then, when you ask for a status, pass the id, and your server can determine how many of that group has been sent, and return back the number that were successful, and unsuccessful, and how many are still pending.  If you want to get fancy, you can also give an indication how much longer it may be before finishing, based on how many other requests are also pending.

But, how you approach this really depends on what you expect when you ask for the status.

Comment: The status returns the number of messages sent or false if no messages are currently being sent.